# How to use Python's str.format and pass named arguments where the name are defined by variables?

Tags: python, string-formatting

I want to print the statement:

```
"{C10} {C20}".format(C10=10, C20=20)
```

but I want to get the names `C10` and `C20` from other parts of the code, put them in variables, and then use the `.format()` method with these variable names.

I simply tried:

```
Parameter1 = 'C10'
Parameter2 = 'C20'

"{C10} {C20}".format(Parameter1=10, Parameter2=20)
```

and I get the `KeyError`.

Is there any way I can use do it using variables instead of hard coding the names `C10` and `C20` directly?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. I'd say you should elaborate on what you are actually trying to achieve. With the little information given in your question, I'd currently say, get rid of the named arguments and just use ``"{} {}".format(10, 20)``

Comment: You *can* pass a dict: `"{C10} {C20}".format(**{Parameter1: 10, Parameter2: 20})`. Alternatively `"{C10} {C20}".format_map({Parameter1: 10, Parameter2: 20})`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Mark's suggestion helped solve my problem

Answer (score 2):

```
Parameter1 = 'C10'
Parameter2 = 'C20'
print("{C10} {C20}".format_map({Parameter1: 10, Parameter2: 20}))
```

Answer (score 0):

`str.format` accepts `{}` or a index inside the curly braces to assign the provided values as per the given index in the braces and not `{variable_name}`

You could just do it like this

```py
parameter1 = 10
parameter2 = 20

formatted_string = "{} {}".format(parameter1, parameter2)
```

(Also the question lacks information required to answer this question)